# FFmpeg - adding offset to an audio channel without reencoding

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a stereo audio in opus format. How do i add offset to only left channel? Is there a way to do this without adding silence(reencoding) to left channel?

input:

```
[right channel...................]
[left channel....................]
```

output:

```
[right channel...................]----2s---
---2s--->[left channel....................]
```

Comment: See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/716320/ffmpeg-placing-audio-at-specific-location-with-complex-filters) and [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation). You can refer to different channels in the same audio with `filter_complex` like `[0:a:0]`, `[0:a:1]`, etc.

Comment: @Chamath Are you sure this can be done without reenconding the audio ?